# Why does FSharpLint suggest, "In F# code, use 'e1 || e2' instead of 'e1 or e2'"

Tags: readability, f#, declarative-programming

If I write the expression,

```
if not (expr1 or expr2) then value
```

I get the following warning from FSharpLint, `In F# code, use 'e1 || e2' instead of 'e1 or e2'`.

Why is using `||` preferred over using `or`? I want to write idiomatic code, but this appears to me to degrade readability. I really like the readability of the `not` function over `!`. the above example expression reads nicer and is much more declarative than the C# counterpart,

```
if (!(expr1 || expr2)) { return value; }
```

So why regress the readability improvement by suggesting double pipes instead of `or`?

Comment: F# has banana clips `(|...|)` and this abomination: `|||>`, and you're worried about `||`, an operator that every curly-brace programmer on the planet instantly recognizes?

Comment: Yes, the scope of this inquiry was intended to be limited to the use of `||` and `or`. I don't think that the syntax of some languages is by itself a justification for idioms of other languages. I think this is especially true when discussing languages of different paradigms.

Comment: MSDN says those two operators are identical.  *Use the one you prefer.*  See also https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpLint/issues/158

Comment: Do you have an opinion/thought on the use of those two operators? Thank you for opening the issue. That was my next stop if not finding a satisfactory response here.

Comment: As a curly-brace programmer, I would probably prefer `||` in simple conditions.  Although the `or` operator would look really nice in query expressions, Microsoft apparently still prefers `||`.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh225374.aspx, about halfway down the page.  Query expressions look very similar in C#, though I find the F# ones slightly more readable.

Comment: Um, crazy guy who hasn't actually used F# speaking, but I'm guessing it's because there is no equivalent `and` operator.  Or did I miss something [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx)?

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt: Ah, that makes sense.  There's an `and` keyword, but it's not used in boolean operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to the FSharpLint folks](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpLint/issues/158), it's not a Lint warning; it's [a warning emitted by the F# compiler](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/1f19d213907d45ca6c5a27aa9cb2910f60b81a9e/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fsi#L1053).

It's probably there because `or` doesn't have a corresponding `and` counterpart.  There is an `and` keyword, but it's not used for boolean operations, so you have to use `&&` anyway, which means its better to use `||` for consistency.

Comment: Which raises the question, why is the language so inconsistent?

Comment: Eh, that's is a minor nit, and an inconsequential one since `&&` and `||` both exist.  The only inconsistency here is the use of `or` as a synonym for `||` without a corresponding `and` synonym for &&.  The `and` keyword [already does three different things](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233249.aspx), which is probably why they decided not to further overload it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That is disappointing. Considering how context driven FSharp already is (type inference), I don't see the other uses of `and` as a hindrance to its use as an alias for `&&`. Thank you for your research efforts.